# I am running my tests in the hardhat environment but it gives me 0 passing all the time

Tags: solidity, ether, hardhat, mocha, chai

I am facing rather unusual behavior from hardhat. I have written my test cases in a file inside test folder when i run `yarn test`on the terminal it gives me 0 passing. Don't have any idea as to why it may be happening. there are two it statements inside my describe wrapper. Following is my testcase

```
describe("Initializing the testing suite", async () => {
  it("checking name of vault LP Token", async () => {
     const vaultLPName = (await vault.name()).toString();
     console.log("Vault LP name", vaultLPName);
     expect(vaultLPName).to.be.equal("eth-usdt");
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this same problem. Did you ever find a solution? I have successfully overrided the subtask above and I can see the console log but I still get a 0 passing output.

Comment: what is your folder structure?

Comment: Consider starting from my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template) and you won't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen if `await ethers.getSigners()` is executed in `describe` clause.

Example that doesn't work (0 passing):

```
describe("ContractName", async () => {

    await ethers.getSigners()

    it("work", async () => {
        ...
    });
```

Fixed:

```
describe("ContractName", async () => {

    it("work", async () => {
        await ethers.getSigners()
        ...
    });
```

Comment: That was my problem, although I exectued await ethers.getContract() in the descibe clause. That lead to the same problem!

Comment: Quite silly, ha? I don't see a reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Cannot think of a reason currently...whatever. You saved my day.

Comment: Has somebody opened up a bug for this? I ran into this too and it very clearly is a bug. This should not stop a test from running.

Comment: Another scenario where the same may happen is if the `test` folder wasn't created in the right place. E.g. I had created it as a sub-folder of `./contracts` by mistake, instead of `.` .

Comment: Once you make this change your `describe` callback no longer needs to be `async` either

Comment: This would have taken me forever to figure out! Thanks! How on earth did you figure it out by the way?

Answer (score 2):

once upon a time, i wrote this, it should be "it", but i wrote "if". no error, just tip "0 passing",

```
describe("Token contract", function () {
    if("Deployment should assign the total supply of tokens to the owner", async function () {
        const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
        const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
        const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();
        const ownerBanlance = await hardhatToken.banlanceOf(owner.address);

        expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBanlance);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `npx hardhat clean` and see if that helps.

Had the same issue after changing some filenames and variables and the above command fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`yarn test` will run the test script in your package.json: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/test/

what I think you're actually trying to do is: `npx hardhat test`
https://hardhat.org/guides/waffle-testing.html

Comment: tried that too but it doesnot seem to work as well.

Comment: Can you share your console output?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by overriding TASK_TEST_GET_TEST_FILES hardhat subtask which actually returns the files found for testing,

```
task(TASK_TEST_GET_TEST_FILES, async ({ testFiles }) => {
  const overriddenTestFiles = glob.sync("tests/**/*.test.ts");
  console.log(testFiles, overriddenTestFiles);
  return overriddenTestFiles;
});
```

Here I used glob to get all the test files in my test directory. (You can modify the pattern in your own way)

Comment: I just changed my testing architecture to be more scalable and it worked like a charm.

Comment: yeah it sometimes doesn't detect the new test files added

Comment: btw can you share your testing arch? (if there is no problem)

Comment: currently it is a private repo. Soon to be public, will share then

Answer (score 0):

How I got it working:

- Check ts.config includes.  Mine didnt had `test` so I changed to `./test`
- Chcked my network config in hardhat.config.ts to have local host
- Check folder structure to match ts.confg

Then changed these imports on my contract.spec.ts

```
// From this
// import { expect, use } from "chai";
// import { ethers } from "hardhat";
// import { solidity } from "ethereum-waffle";

// To this
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers";
import { expect, use } from "chai";
import { solidity } from "ethereum-waffle";

import hh, { ethers } from "hardhat";

import {
  Compound,
  Compound__factory,
  Vault,
  Vault__factory,
} from "../build/types";

use(solidity);
```

```
    local: {
      url: "http://localhost:8545",
      accounts:
        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
    },
```

````json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["./scripts", "./test", "./typechain"],
  "files": ["./hardhat.config.ts"]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is your hardhat config is written in javascript format instead of typescript format.

As specified in [hardhat doc](https://hardhat.org/guides/typescript.html):

> Hardhat will automatically enable its TypeScript support if your config file ends in .ts and is written in valid TypeScript. This requires a few changes to work properly.

So if your test case is in typescript format but your hardhat config is in javascript format, 0 passing will be produced all the time.

Detailed behavior can be seen in [test.js](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/hardhat%402.9.2/packages/hardhat-core/src/builtin-tasks/test.ts) (code below found in hardhat v2.9.2):

```
const jsFiles = await glob(path.join(config.paths.tests, "**/*.js"));

if (!isRunningWithTypescript(config)) {
  return jsFiles;
}

const tsFiles = await glob(path.join(config.paths.tests, "**/*.ts"));

return [...jsFiles, ...tsFiles];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I installed the helmet after I created the folders `tests`, `scripts`, etc.
The problem was that I created a `tests` folder instead of `test`. I don't know why, but hardhat didn't rename it and didn't create a new one, so it didn't see my tests.
Check the name of your test folder, maybe you need to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this issue is that the test folder is not located in the default location provided from hardhat.
In details, Hardhat default configuration requires a folder called 'test' created in root of your project. If you change this folder name or location where you want to execute your tests, the program'll say that '0 passing'.

To solve this issue, in your `hardhat.config.js` you must specify new test folder path, adding the `paths` key and the new location inside `tests` key.

Example:

*Location my Hardhat tests:* {project_root_folder}/**tests/smartcontract**

*Hardhat.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.0",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  paths: {
    tests: "./tests/smartcontract"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do `yarn hardhat test`. If this also doesn't work you can put following code into your hardhat config.

```
 paths: {
        tests: "./tests",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same problem your package name needs to be called "test" or you need to set specific path in hardhat config :)

Comment: Your answer does not provide any more useful information, as other (at least 2) answers say the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename hardhat.config.js -> hardhat.config.ts (from JavaScript to TypeScript!)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. What fixed it for me was that the anonymous function that "describe" and "it" take should be NOT be declared 'async' if there's no 'await' in its direct scope.

```
describe("something", () => {
    ....
    describe("something else", async () => {
        const {deployer} = await  getNamedAccounts();
         .... 
    });
})
```